# UIImagePickerController AllowsEditing not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller, xamarin

I am using UIImagePickerController to allow the user to take a picture. I want to allow him/her to edit it afterwards but, whatever I do, I get nothing.

Here is my code (I am using Xamarin):

```
UIImagePickerController imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController ();
                // set our source to the camera
                imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
                // set what media types
                //imagePicker.MediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes (UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera);
                // show the camera controls
                imagePicker.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext;
                imagePicker.ShowsCameraControls = true;
                imagePicker.AllowsEditing = true;
                imagePicker.SetEditing (true,true);
                imagePicker.PreferredContentSize = new SizeF(900,600);
                imagePicker.CameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Photo;
                imagePicker.Title="taste.eat. image";
                // attach the delegate
                imagePicker.Delegate = new ImagePickerDelegate();
                // show the picker
                NavigationController.PresentViewController(imagePicker, true,null);
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

I have followed the tutorial and I am getting to the screen with the rectangle, but if i pan or zoom it just snaps back to the center once I lift my finger. Is it possible to get to this screen from the photos application?

[image: Image from the photos application]

Comment: Hey, have you figured it out? ive got the same problem.

Comment: From my understanding `allowsEditing` simply allows you to crop the photo. It does not actually bring up the iOS photo editing functionality in the Photo App, as you show in the screenshot

Comment: It only allows you to crop. Sorry.

Answer (score 48):

When using `UIImagePickerController's delegate` 
 method - `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`, we get the image using

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

This code will always return the original image, even if editing is ON.

Try using

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

This will return the edited image if editing is ON.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This simple mistake on my end was driving me mad, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 28):

The `AllowsEditing` property simply allows the user to crop to a square if picking an image and trim the video if picking a video.

Any other functionality needs to be implemented with custom UI and code.

See this question:[iPhone SDK - How to customize the crop rect in UIImagePickerController with allowsEditing on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306861/iphone-sdk-how-to-customize-the-crop-rect-in-uiimagepickercontroller-with-allo)

What you are showing in the screenshot is not part of `UIImagePickerController`, unfortunately

Answer (score 7):

**SWIFT 3**

I was having a hard time returning the cropped image (simple mistake on my end). Instead of using UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage, you need UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage. See below:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the cropped image.
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage

    // Set yourImageView to display the selected image.
    yourImage.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT 4+**

There have been some changes after Swift 4. `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` changed to `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage`.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as! UIImage
    imageView.image = selectedImage
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to `enable filters` by just changing property like `allowsEditing = YES`. It will only display a cropping tool. As per your screenshot it's look like you have integrated some buggy open source library and without looking at the source code it would be difficult to fix your center cropping bug.

Better to post some concrete detail about your implementation or switch to [standard open source library](https://github.com/gobackspaces/DLCImagePickerController).

Answer (score 0):

It will be work like this way.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage

    userPhoto.image = selectedImage

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```