# Whats the `allowsEditing` flag good for?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I wanted to use `UIImagePickerController` to select an image, crop it to a given size (using a given aspect ratio) and to set it on my `UIImageView`.

So I did the following:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController();
picker.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext;
picker.allowsEditing = true;
picker.delegate = self;

self.present(picker, animated: true);
```

When I know try it I can select an image and I get leaded to the "move and scaling" view of iOS. But actually.... I have no crop frame and also moving and scaling is a little bit "strange" and it does not matter how I move or scale the image, the result is always the same. The result is always just showing a small section of the original picture (top left corner).

So what is the editing mode good for at all if it has zero functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController AllowsEditing not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024648/uiimagepickercontroller-allowsediting-not-working)

Comment: *A Boolean value indicating whether the user is allowed to edit a selected still image or movie.* See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619137-allowsediting

Comment: both sources are not containing answers to my question.

Comment: There is also a bug with this since iOS6. In the "move and scale" screen it does not move and scale properly. This was broken in iOS 6 and has not been fixed yet. I have an open radar from 2012 for it and keep pestering Apple.

Comment: whats the recommend way to crop an image than ? to let user select the crop area?

Comment: Until this is fixed the only way is to do it yourself. I am sure there will be frameworks that can be used for this.

Comment: Nah... all I found are too old or too bad... damn. this is sad. million libs for android but 0 for ios

Comment: Amazing. I am finding all sorts of bugs tonight that have been around for several iOS versions.

Comment: Recently I've started to use `allowEditing` in couple `UIImagePickerController` projects, and it seems to work in the simulator, and on all the devices. I'm in Xcode 10, iOS 11...