# Xcode - image not appearing in UIImageView after it has been picked by the user

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to make an app in which you can 'compose' fake tweets, but my code seems to not add an image picked by a user to the UIImageView I have set up for the twitter profile picture.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{    
    @IBOutlet weak var twitterName: UILabel!    
    @IBOutlet weak var twitterUsername: UILabel!    
    @IBOutlet weak var twitterProfilePic: UIImageView!    
    @IBOutlet weak var twitterTweet: UILabel!    
    @IBOutlet weak var inputTwitterName: UITextField!    
    @IBOutlet weak var inputTwitterUsername: UITextField!    
    @IBOutlet weak var inputTweet: UITextField!    
    @IBAction func chooseTwitterImage(_ sender: Any) {        

    let profilePic = UIImagePickerController()
    profilePic.delegate = self        
    profilePic.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary        
    profilePic.allowsEditing = false        
    self.present(profilePic, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func makeTweetButton(_ sender: Any) {        
    twitterName.text = (inputTwitterName.text)!        
    twitterUsername.text = (inputTwitterUsername.text)!        
    twitterTweet.text = (inputTweet.text)!        

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let profilePic = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        {
            twitterProfilePic.image = profilePic                
        }                
        else
        {                
            print("ERROR PICKING IMAGE")                
        }
    }        
}
```

It doesn't seem to make any difference to the UIImageView... Help.

Comment: The `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is nested within the `makeTweetButton` method. Can you try to move it to be a method of class `ViewController`?

Comment: Yes, it is working now! But I have another problem. I have changed allowsEditing to true, and when I click choose after cropping the photo it freezes the app. Any thoughts?

Comment: It should be another question. Would appreciate if you could accept the answer to the initial problem.

Comment: When enabling `allowsEditing`, you might need to implement the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` method to have the result saved.

Comment: How and where in my code would I implement this? Would it be after the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo?

Comment: This other question about [UIImagePickerController AllowsEditing not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024648/uiimagepickercontroller-allowsediting-not-working) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah thanks, manages to fix the problem myself but thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` nested method to be a class of `ViewController` solves the problem.