# Detect when camera flash button is pressed?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-camera, camera-overlay, camera-flash

I have a UIImagePickerController, used for taking pictures. There is a lightning button in the top left corner. When it is pressed, it brings up the three options: Auto, On, Off. These buttons refer to whether the flash mode is auto, on, or off. I want to detect when this lightning button is pressed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that's possible with the default UIImagePickerController, you'd probably have to subclass it, and work that up on your own.

(Personally I'd avoid using UIPicker, and instead move onto AVFoundation for camera use, as it's a touch limited, and there's a rather annoying bug with it's "allow edit" portion).

You might be able to find a custom library to do this function, but I'm not sure what would solve it. Good luck. :)

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024648/uiimagepickercontroller-allowsediting-not-working)